# Построение гистограммы WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно сделать Гистограмму в wpf, но не простую, внутри каждой колонки гистограммы, должны быть другие маленькие колонки, сумма значений которых, равна родительской.
Каким образом это лучше реализовать, какие библиотеки лучше использовать?
Так же прикрепляю изображение, с примером, как должна выглядеть одна колонка

[image: Пример одной колонки]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну как вариант, это рассматривать каждый большой столбец за некий объект, который содержит в себе еще по несколько объектов, тогда в таком случае подойдет `ItemsControl`, который вложен в другой `ItemsControl`.

То есть делаем примерно такой стиль:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat={}{0}%}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Medium"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <ProgressBar Background="Transparent" Foreground="#8AC976" 
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 Margin="-.5 0 0 0"
                                 Value="{Binding Total, Mode=OneWay}"
                                 Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin=".5 0 0 0">
                                    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=.}" 
                                             Orientation="Vertical"
                                             Width="15"
                                             BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                             Background="Transparent" 
                                             Foreground="#67AF7D"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat={}{0}%}" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Здесь как я уже и говорил, создается `ItemsControl`, который размещает объекты в один ряд, переопределяем стиль элемента и вставляем туда еще один `ItemsControl`, который также размещает объекты в ряд, а в его шаблоне указываем вертикальный `ProgressBar`. Остальное, это "финтифлюшки в виде текста и заднего фона "большого" столбца.

Все остальное уже зависит от ваших данных, какие они, что хотите вывести и так далее. Лично в моем примере идет класс `ItemModel`, который принимает значения и подсчитывает общее значение:

```
class ItemModel
{

    public List<double> Values { get; set; }

    public double Total => Values?.Any() == true ? Values.Sum() : 0;

    public ItemModel(params double[] values)
    {
        Values = new List<double>(values);
    }
}
```

И в основной VM два свойства: коллекция с числами, а также общее число:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
    public double Total => Items?.Any() == true ? Items.SelectMany(x=>x.Values).Sum() : 0;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>
        {
            new ItemModel(.5,1,2.22),
            new ItemModel(15,50.01,7),
            new ItemModel(.2,20,6.2),
            new ItemModel(3,1,.03),
        };
    }
```

Тут опять же, я все сделал на скорую руку, что бы протестировать сам дизайн, вам же стоит все это сделать под себя.

В итоге результат получается примерно следующий:

[image: Result]

Имея это уже дальше можно играться. Добавить автоматическое обновление данных, может анимации навесить, стиль подстроить под себя и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Для различного рода инфографики я бы обратил внимание на
https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts
и
https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot

Пример для Live-Charts:

Возьмем такую же модель

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public List<double> Values { get; set; }

    public double Total => Values?.Any() == true ? Values.Sum() : 0;

    public ItemModel(params double[] values)
    {
        Values = new List<double>(values);
    }
}
```

Наша ViewModel

```
public class HistogramViewModel
{
    public HistogramViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>
        {
            new ItemModel(.5,1,2.22),
            new ItemModel(15,50.01,7),
            new ItemModel(.2,20,6.2),
            new ItemModel(3,1,.03),
        };

        InitializeComponent();

        Formatter = value => value.ToString("P");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ChartValues<double> Values1 => new ChartValues<double> 
        (Items.SelectMany(x => x.Values));

    public ChartValues<double> Values2 => new ChartValues<double> 
        (Items.Select(x => x.Total));

    public Func<double, string> Formatter { get; set; }
}
```

Наша View

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.Ext.Views.HistogramExampleView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf">
<Grid Height="400">
    <lvc:CartesianChart Width="200">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:ColumnSeries Fill="#8AC976"
                              ColumnPadding="1"
                              MaxColumnWidth="50"
                              DataLabels="True"
                              Values="{Binding Values2}"/>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis ShowLabels="False"/>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis ShowLabels="False" MaxValue="100"/>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
    <lvc:CartesianChart Width="200">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:ColumnSeries Fill="#67AF7D"
                              ColumnPadding="1"                                  
                              MaxColumnWidth="15"                                                               
                              Values="{Binding Values1}"/>                
        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis ShowLabels="False"/>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis ShowLabels="False" MaxValue="100" />
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>        
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Минус тут в том, что на одном чарте не расположишь колонки разной ширины, один фиг максимальная ширина колонки равна ширине грида / количество колонок. Приходится лепить два чарта и выравнивать максимальное значение по Y

Еще проблема возникнет, если надо в главных колонках выводить разное количество подчиненных, думаю, тут надо переопределять шаблон колонки для чарта.